# deployment of virtual machine from virtual box to ESXI

Tags: virtualbox, esxi, system-administration, server-administration

Actually I'm working on an administration and system project. I'm using  ESXI, virtual box and OVH. 
lastly, I got an error which blocked me and didn't let me to complete my configuration. the error is

```
<OperatingSystemSection ovf:id="80">
      <Info>The kind of installed guest operating system</Info>
      <Description>RedHat_64</Description>
      <vbox:OSType ovf:required="false">RedHat_64</vbox:OSType>
    </OperatingSystemSection>
```

let me explain to clarify the problem.
as anyone knows that before deploying anything to the cloud we must pass through a development phase. After that, if everything is good, we do a migration of all our resources that we have configured into a cloud environment.
Now here, I used in the development phase: virtual box, and I have a virtual machine that I have exported from VBOX to put it into the esxi enviroment which is located in OVH.
I converted the exported VM from  ova to ovf by following this tutorial: [1]: https://felixcentmerino.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/migrate-virtual-machine-from-oracle-virtualbox-to-esxi-5-5/
but when I would like to deploy the ovf file to the ESXi I get the error that is mentioned above.
could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace by:

```
<OperatingSystemSection ovf:id="107">
      <Info>The kind of installed guest operating system</Info>
      <!-- <Description>RedHat_64</Description> -->
        <!-- <vbox:OSType ovf:required="false">RedHat_64</vbox:OSType>  -->
        <vbox:OSType ovf:required="false">centos64Guest</vbox:OSType> 
    </OperatingSystemSection>
```